# Send raw request (http post files data) with winsocks in C/C++

Tags: c++, file-upload, winsock2

I work on a small project that will send a file (image) with an c++ application and receive it on a web server over **http** (no ftp).

I use **winsocks** for sending the query, but my problem is :

```
    std::string query=
    "POST /test/upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: site.net\r\n"
    "User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36\r\n"
    "Connection: Keep-alive\r\n\r\n"
    "Content-Length: "+FileSize+"\r\n"
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"

    "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tmp\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"
        "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
        +StrData+
    "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr--\r\n";
```

i need to put the HEX of my file here -> **StrData** but i don't know how to do that ?...

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to send the file data in HEX.  You need to send the file's original raw binary data as-is instead.  Assuming the size of the file is small, you can stuff it into a `std::string` as-is.

BTW, your request is malformed - you have too many `\r\n` on the `Connection` header. The extra `\r\n` belongs after the last header instead. And do not use a `Content-Length` header with `multipart` content types, as they are self-terminating - especially since you are specifying the wrong value anyway.  If you want to specify a `Content-Length`, you have to calculate the length of the complete MIME data before then creating the headers that proceed it.

Try this instead:

```
std::ifstream File("filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std:::ios::ate);
if (file)
{
    std::ifstream::pos_type FileSize = File.tellp();
    File.seekg(0);

    std::string StrData;
    if (FileSize > 0)
    {
        StrData.resize(FileSize);
        File.read(&StrData[0], FileSize);
    }

    File.close();

    std::string query =
        "POST /test/upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: site.net\r\n"
        "User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36\r\n"
        "Connection: Keep-alive\r\n"
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tmp\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"
        "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        +StrData+
        "\r\n"
        "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr--\r\n";

    // send query ...
}
```

With that said, it is better not to try to stuff the entire HTTP request into a single `std::string`.  Send the initial request headers first, then send the raw file data next, then send the terminating boundary last.  For example:

```
std::fstream File("filename", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (file)
{
    char chunk[1024];
    std::streamsize chunksize;

    std::string str =
        "POST /test/upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: site.net\r\n"
        "User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36\r\n"
        "Connection: Keep-alive\r\n"
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr\r\n"
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"tmp\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"
        "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
        "\r\n";

    // send str ...

    do
    {
        chunksize = File.readsome(chunk, sizeof(chunk));
        if (chunksize < 1)
            break;

        // send chunk up to chunksize bytes ...
    }
    while (true);

    File.close();

    str =
        "\r\n"
        "------WebKitFormBoundarym9PgiUg6fjxm2Hpr--\r\n";

    // send str ...
```

Comment: I think your right this version is better, i'll try, but i can send a query like that in several times ?

Comment: Yes. Unlike UDP, TCP is a byte stream. You do not have to send everything in a single `send()` call. You can use multiple `send()` calls.